# JVM crashed when calling native c++ method

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am trying to call c++ native method on java. How to make the method not to crash.

I wrote a method in c++ and compiled it into a dll, then load it in java:

```
public class nativeContent {
    protected static class cppFunc {
        public static final String[] dlls = {
                "python311.dll",
                "libwinpthread-1.dll",
                "libgcc_s_seh-1.dll",
                "libstdc++-6.dll",
                "BML_T.dll"
        };
        static {
            for (String dll: dlls) {
                File dllFile = new File(dll);
                try {
                    if(!dllFile.exists()) Files.copy(Objects.requireNonNull(agentMain.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + dll)), Path.of("./" + dll));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("[BML][ERROR] Could not release dependence:" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.load(dllFile.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
        public native boolean IsPrepared();
        public native void setCharset(String charset);
        public native boolean needTransform(String classloader, String classname);
        public native boolean handleBytes(CtClass target);
        public native void runPyFunc(int id, Object ...args);
    }
    public static cppFunc INSTANCE = new cppFunc();
}
```

The problem appeared on method "needTransform", I called it in the following method:

```
@Override
public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class<?> classBeingRedefined, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer){
    if(nativeContent.INSTANCE.needTransform(loader.getName(), className)){
        System.out.println("[BML][INFO] Transforming " + loader.getName() + "::" + className);
           ...............
    }
}
```

The definition in c++:

library.h:

```
class cppFunc{
        static std::string lastClass;
    public:
        static JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL IsPrepared(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance);
        static JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL needTransform(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, jstring classloader, jstring classname);
        static JNIEXPORT void JNICALL setCharset(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, jstring charset);
        static JNIEXPORT void JNICALL handleBytes(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, jobject target);
        static JNIEXPORT void JNICALL runPyFunc(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, jint id, jobjectArray args);
};

JNINativeMethod methods[] = {
        {str("IsPrepared"), str("()Z"), (void *)cppFunc::IsPrepared},
        {str("needTransform"), str("(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Z"), (void *)cppFunc::needTransform},
        {str("setCharset"), str("(Ljava/lang/String;)V"), (void *)cppFunc::setCharset},
        {str("handleBytes"), str("(Ljavassist/CtClass;)Z"), (void *)cppFunc::handleBytes},
        {str("runPyFunc"), str("(I[Ljava/lang/Object;)V"), (void *)cppFunc::runPyFunc}
};
```

library.cpp:

```
jboolean cppFunc::needTransform(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, jstring classloader, jstring classname){
    auto* tools = (CustomJEnv*)env;
    cppFunc::lastClass = tools->ToString(classloader) + "::" + tools->ToString(classname);
    return (bool)transformingClasses.count(cppFunc::lastClass);
}
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *javaVm, void *reserved){
    jvm = javaVm;
    CustomJEnv* env = GetEnv("BML");
    jclass target = env->FindClass("gwy/bml/agent/nativeContent$cppFunc");
    env->RegisterNatives(target, methods, sizeof(methods) / sizeof(JNINativeMethod));
    fstream f("bml_index.py");
    if(!f.good()){
        f.open("bml_index.py", std::ios_base::out);
        f<<" ";
        f.close();
    }
    return JNI_VERSION_9;
}
```

Then the error report in console:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000001f8d30f5fa5, pid=29596, tid=30888
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (17.0.6+9) (build 17.0.6+9-LTS-190)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (17.0.6+9-LTS-190, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed
 class ptrs, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# v  ~BufferBlob::jni_fast_GetCharField
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# F:\minecraft\BML_Test\.minecraft\hs_err_pid29596.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

error file:

```
---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000014051bc09c0):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=34784, stack(0x0000002504200000,0x0000002504300000)]

Stack: [0x0000002504200000,0x0000002504300000],  sp=0x00000025042fbbf8,  free space=1006k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  0x00000140608e5fa5

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J 1210  gwy.bml.agent.nativeContent$cppFunc.needTransform(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Z (0 bytes) @ 0x0000014061058a0b [0x00000140610589a0+0x000000000000006b]
J 583 c1 gwy.bml.agent.bmlTransformer.transform(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/security/ProtectionDomain;[B)[B (214 bytes) @ 0x00000140595040ac [0x0000014059503f40+0x000000000000016c]
J 582 c1 java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer.transform(Ljava/lang/Module;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/security/ProtectionDomain;[B)[B java.instrument@17.0.6 (15 bytes) @ 0x000001405950070c [0x0000014059500640+0x00000000000000cc]
J 581 c1 sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(Ljava/lang/Module;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/security/ProtectionDomain;[B)[B java.instrument@17.0.6 (100 bytes) @ 0x000001405950191c [0x00000140595016e0+0x000000000000023c]
J 580 c1 sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(Ljava/lang/Module;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/security/ProtectionDomain;[BZ)[B java.instrument@17.0.6 (73 bytes) @ 0x0000014059500d84 [0x0000014059500ae0+0x00000000000002a4]
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
J 1228  java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/String;[BIILjava/security/ProtectionDomain;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class; java.base@17.0.6 (0 bytes) @ 0x0000014061059b63 [0x0000014061059aa0+0x00000000000000c3]
j  java.lang.System$2.defineClass(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/String;[BLjava/security/ProtectionDomain;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;+10 java.base@17.0.6
j  jdk.internal.reflect.ClassDefiner.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BIILjava/lang/ClassLoader;)Ljava/lang/Class;+27 java.base@17.0.6
j  jdk.internal.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run()Ljdk/internal/reflect/MagicAccessorImpl;+21 java.base@17.0.6
j  jdk.internal.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1 java.base@17.0.6
j  java.security.AccessController.executePrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;+29 java.base@17.0.6
j  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;)Ljava/lang/Object;+5 java.base@17.0.6
j  jdk.internal.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Class;IZZLjava/lang/Class;)Ljdk/internal/reflect/MagicAccessorImpl;+755 java.base@17.0.6
j  jdk.internal.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateConstructor(Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Class;I)Ljdk/internal/reflect/ConstructorAccessor;+14 java.base@17.0.6
j  jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87 java.base@17.0.6
j  jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+5 java.base@17.0.6
j  java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller([Ljava/lang/Object;ZLjava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;+65 java.base@17.0.6
j  java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+30 java.base@17.0.6
j  java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;Ljava/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler;)Ljava/lang/Object;+21 java.base@17.0.6
j  java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;[Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler;)Ljava/lang/Object;+31 java.base@17.0.6
j  sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser$1.run()Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;+33 java.base@17.0.6
j  sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser$1.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1 java.base@17.0.6
j  java.security.AccessController.executePrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;+29 java.base@17.0.6
j  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;)Ljava/lang/Object;+5 java.base@17.0.6
j  sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.annotationForMap(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;+9 java.base@17.0.6
j  sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljdk/internal/reflect/ConstantPool;Ljava/lang/Class;Z[Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;+267 java.base@17.0.6
j  sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2([BLjdk/internal/reflect/ConstantPool;Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/util/Map;+41 java.base@17.0.6
j  sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations([BLjdk/internal/reflect/ConstantPool;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/util/Map;+12 java.base@17.0.6
j  java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(I)Ljava/lang/Class$AnnotationData;+9 java.base@17.0.6
j  java.lang.Class.annotationData()Ljava/lang/Class$AnnotationData;+26 java.base@17.0.6
j  java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;+6 java.base@17.0.6
j  org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.PatternParser.<init>(Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/Configuration;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)V+119
j  org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.PatternParser.<init>(Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/Configuration;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)V+5
j  org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.createPatternParser(Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/Configuration;)Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/pattern/PatternParser;+42
j  org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout$SerializerBuilder.build()Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/layout/AbstractStringLayout$Serializer;+33
j  org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.<init>(Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/Configuration;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/pattern/RegexReplacement;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/layout/PatternSelector;Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;ZZZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V+137
j  org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.<init>(Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/Configuration;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/pattern/RegexReplacement;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/layout/PatternSelector;Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;ZZZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/layout/PatternLayout$1;)V+18
j  org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout$Builder.build()Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/layout/PatternLayout;+45
j  org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.setToDefault()V+43
j  org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration.<init>()V+9
j  org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/net/URI;)V+31
j  org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.createContext(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/net/URI;)Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/LoggerContext;+7
j  org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.locateContext(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/util/Map$Entry;Ljava/net/URI;)Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/LoggerContext;+123
j  org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/util/Map$Entry;ZLjava/net/URI;)Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/LoggerContext;+38
j  org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;ZLjava/net/URI;)Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/LoggerContext;+7
j  org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Z)Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/LoggerContext;+5
j  org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/Object;Z)Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/LoggerContext;+8
j  org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/Object;Z)Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/spi/LoggerContext;+6
j  org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Z)Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/spi/LoggerContext;+9
j  org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/spi/LoggerContext;+21
j  org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext()Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/spi/LoggerContext;+46
j  org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;+1
j  org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/slf4j/Logger;+2
j  org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/slf4j/Logger;+6
j  org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/slf4j/Logger;+4
j  com.mojang.logging.LogUtils.getLogger()Lorg/slf4j/Logger;+6
j  net.minecraft.client.main.Main.<clinit>()V+0
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

siginfo: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005), reading address 0x0000000000000000


Register to memory mapping:

RIP=0x00000140608e5fa5 is at code_begin+37 in 
[CodeBlob (0x00000140608e5f10)]
Framesize: 0
BufferBlob (0x00000140608e5f10) used for jni_fast_GetCharField
RAX=0x0 is NULL
RBX=0x0000014051bc0c68 points into unknown readable memory: 0x00007fff5803a650 | 50 a6 03 58 ff 7f 00 00
RCX=0x0000014051bc0c68 points into unknown readable memory: 0x00007fff5803a650 | 50 a6 03 58 ff 7f 00 00
RDX=0x0 is NULL
RSP=0x00000025042fbbf8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000014051bc09c0
RBP=0x00000025042fbc20 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000014051bc09c0
RSI=0x0000000517b73020 is an oop: gwy.bml.agent.nativeContent$cppFunc 
{0x0000000517b73020} - klass: 'gwy/bml/agent/nativeContent$cppFunc'
 - ---- fields (total size 2 words):
RDI=0x0000000513d8b9b8 is an oop: java.lang.String 
{0x0000000513d8b9b8} - klass: 'java/lang/String'
 - string: "jdk/internal/reflect/GeneratedConstructorAccessor1"
R8 =0x0000000000000032 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0 is NULL
R10=0x000000000000000c is an unknown value
R11=0x0000000000000002 is an unknown value
R12=0x0 is NULL
R13=0x0000000800c01000 is a pointer to class: 
gwy.bml.agent.bmlTransformer {0x0000000800c01008}
 - instance size:     3
 - klass size:        71
 - access:            public synchronized 
 - state:             fully_initialized
 - name:              'gwy/bml/agent/bmlTransformer'
 - super:             'java/lang/Object'
 - sub:               
 - arrays:            NULL
 - methods:           Array<T>(0x000001407d402a28)
 - method ordering:   Array<T>(0x00000008008f3128)
 - default_methods:   Array<T>(0x000001407d402e10)
 - default vtable indices:   Array<T>(0x000001407d402e20)
 - local interfaces:  Array<T>(0x000001407d4029f8)
 - trans. interfaces: Array<T>(0x000001407d4029f8)
 - constants:         constant pool [168]/operands[30] {0x000001407d4023c8} for 'gwy/bml/agent/bmlTransformer' cache=0x000001407d403a00
 - class loader data:  loader data: 0x000001407d8e0be0 for instance a 'jdk/internal/loader/ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader'{0x00000005160cd1c8}
 - source file:       'bmlTransformer.java'
 - class annotations:       Array<T>(0x0000000000000000)
 - class type annotations:  Array<T>(0x0000000000000000)
 - field annotations:       Array<T>(0x0000000000000000)
 - field type annotations:  Array<T>(0x0000000000000000)
 - inner classes:     Array<T>(0x000001407d402df0)
 - nest members:     Array<T>(0x00000008005cfc78)
 - permitted subclasses:     Array<T>(0x00000008005cfc78)
 - java mirror:       a 'java/lang/Class'{0x0000000517b7a008} = 'gwy/bml/agent/bmlTransformer'
 - vtable length      7  (start addr: 0x0000000800c011c8)
 - itable length      6 (start addr: 0x0000000800c01200)
 - ---- static fields (0 words):
 - ---- non-static fields (2 words):
 - private final 'args' 'Ljava/lang/String;' @12 
 - private final 'pool' 'Ljavassist/ClassPool;' @16 
 - non-static oop maps: 12-16 
R14=0x0 is NULL
R15=0x0000014051bc09c0 is a thread
```

it looks like that the error was thrown in method "needTransform", so I set a breakpoint on the first line of the method "needTransform", but the breakpoint wasn't hit.

Comment: `jclass target = env->FindClass("gwy/bml/agent/nativeContent$cppFunc");` -- Your code does not check for errors.  What if `target` is null?  The error: `siginfo: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005), reading address 0x0000000000000000` suggests that you are trying to read from the null pointer.

Comment: Also, it is not wise to write JNI code without any error checking, without any error recovery, and without throwing an exception back to the Java if there is an issue.  If you had done that, then possibly you would have a better experience than have the JVM crash.

Comment: JNI is incredibly hard to get right, I suggest you take a look at [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna).

Comment: From a distance, having one executable with 3 different technologies Java/C++/Python (assuming you load python.dll in C++ to do some python stuff as well). Is asking for lifetime/memory access issues somewhere at sometime. (All 3 languages use memory in totally different manners). Is there a reason you must do this (run all code in the same process). I would at least have a look at using value semantic (copying data not passing references/pointers) and/or running each technolgy in its own process with RPC calls (grpc) in between. (unless it would hurt perfromance too much)

Comment: @PepijnKramer Or maybe use [Graal](https://www.graalvm.org/python/).

Comment: Yes, JNI is for those who know what they are doing, and know exactly how to diagnose issues.  It isn't for the novice -- if you are asking others why the JVM crashed using JNI, then it may be time to look for alternatives.

Comment: What does `tools->ToString` do if its argument is `null` ?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The point I was making is that mixing languages with different life-cycle and (value/reference) semantic is always going to be problematic when you pass values by reference (e.g. C#/C++ you will need to pin memory to avoid garbage collector from interfering etc.. etc..)

Comment: What makes me ensure target isn't null is that method `IsPrepared` and `setCharset` was called without errors. And `target` is used to register native methods. It proved that registering methods succeeded and 'target' is not `null`

Comment: @Nahida *It proved that ...* -- That still does not address the issue of not having error checking right at that line of code where you are setting `target`.  Why wait until other functions are called before you actually claim where you are doing the checking?  Another set of eyes looking at your code should (or would) point out this deficiency.

Comment: I forgot to say that This error was thrown at the initialization stage. Python.dll is loaded and python was inited. But no python object or code was used or executed. `tools->ToString` was checked just now and it worked correctly.

Comment: @Nahida Go back to the error: `siginfo: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005), reading address 0x0000000000000000` -- That means one of your pointers, wherever they come from, is NULL, and you are attempting to access it.  That's the cause of the crash -- why the crash occurs, or why that pointer is NULL, you need to investigate.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you, but I really don't know what makes it. I set breakpoints on every line and followed the program running. But all the variables was correct. As long as the program executed `needTransform` and prepares to execute `needTransform`(the first line of this function even wasn't excuted) the error happened.

Comment: It seems like the access to `null` happened in jvm instead of my dll file. This is what confused me.

Comment: When I debug the dll, the debugger told me that the location of the error is `<unknown <unknown> 0x0000027c88c92cb8>`

Comment: @Nahida *It seems like the access to null happened in jvm instead of my dll file. This is what confused me.*  And that is the type of behavior that happens when you make a call in JNI that either fails or throws an exception, and because you do no error checking you just continue plodding along and wind up corrupting your JVM's memory.  Do as suggested and **check every last JNI call you make for both errors and exceptions**.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch *JNI is incredibly hard to get right...*  Keep it simple, **always** check for errors and exceptions, and don't do anything in native code that can be done in Java and then *passed* to native code.  JNA has its own issues, and you have no control over the native implementation.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Good advice in general, but I'm not the one crazy enough to thunk out to C++ in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help. The problem has been solved. The access to `null` located the most amazing place. When the `jvm` loads the class `jdk/internal/reflect/GeneratedConstructorAccessor1` , `loader.getName()` will return `null`. Then `null` will be passed into the native method `needTransform`, and `jvm` will try to convert `null` to jstring. Finally it crashed.

Comment: Make that a answer instead of a comment so someone else can discover this issue too.